# virtualbox share one git repository for host and guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wordpress

What I'm trying to do is to maintain one git repository for my local WordPress development workflow. After much trial and error* I've managed to successfully install Ubuntu 12.04lts on my Windows 7 machine and setup xampp and WordPress. My idea is to be able to clone the vm for additional projects. (btw I have relatively very little experience in the *nix world, and am new to git as well - tho I've been using subversion (tortoiseSVN for years.)

So I have a Ubuntu 12.04lts guest running in windows 7. I have a myProject folder on windows with git repositories in sub directories (e.g myProjects/aProject}. I've installed xampp and WordPress 3.8 in the Ubuntu guest. I've shared the specific theme directory from my repository (e.g. myProjects/aProject/wp-content/themes/customtheme through virtualbox and it is usable on the guest as /media/sf_customtheme.

In the Ubuntu WordPress themes directory (/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes) I've created a symlink to /media/sf_customtheme (named customtheme.) If I click on the link it shows me the theme files.

However, when I log into WP and go to Appearance > Themes I get the following error: Notice: /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/customtheme is not readable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/theme.php on line 466

I've added myUserName to the vboxsf group and to the www-data group. Still no go. I suspect this must be some kind of permissions thing but I haven't been able to find any thing that helps. Oh yeah the shared folder is auto mounted.

---

*tried vagrant, tried Linux Mint in virtualbox, tried wp multisite - unable to get them working for me.

Comment: Vagrant is the perfect solution here, what wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for development purposes, you can try opening the permissions of `/media/sf_customtheme/' to being completely open. This is **not** recommended for a production environment though.

To do this, on the Ubuntu guest just run `sudo chmod 777 /media/sf_customtheme/`.